I/O error on GET request for "https://localhost/application/o/{name}/.well-known/openid-configuration": Connection refused
I'm trying to hook up Spring Security to use a basic Authentik setup. Authentik is running in Docker via Docker Compose, as is my Spring Boot service.
FYI, I've replaced the name of my application with {name} in my question; its not actually {name} in my config.
I've tried the following roots for the URIs in my application.yaml file:

localhost
http://localhost
https://localhost
http://{name of container}
{name of container}
0.0.0.0

Authentik is running on port 80/443. It has the vanilla self-signed cert. If I go to the following URL in a browser, I get the JSON response as expected:
http://localhost/application/o/{name}/.well-known/openid-configuration
I can't for the life of me figure out why I can't get Spring Security to talk to Authentik on startup. I've been at this for days.

Found the solution. No modification necessary to the Authentik docker compose file. Modification was necessary for my app's docker compose file, however. I had to add the Authentik network to my app's container, and add this at the bottom:
networks:
  authentik_default:
    driver: bridge
    name: authentik_default
    external: true

Name of the network was ascertained by doing a docker network ls while Authentik was running. That told me the name of the Authentik network. I then modified my application.yaml so it looked at the container name instead of localhost. I was able to obtain the container name of Authentik's "server" container via docker container ls. Hope this helps someone else!
